# How to properly create centered multi-lines sub-captions with subfig?

Tags: spacing, captions, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

I'm having difficulties with subcaptions, which aren't well centered under their subfigure, and doesn't have proper horizontal andvertical spacings.  Here's a MWE code to show the issues:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup{figurename=Figure,margin=1cm,format=hang,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={it}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0cm,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={up}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]  % [ h ], [ b ], [ t ], [ p ]
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty,justification=centering}
\subfloat[
    $x = 5$ ; $y = 0,33$.
    \newline
    $u = 1$ ; $v \approx 0.87$.
    \newline
    $p \approx 1.75$ ; $q \approx 0.95$.
    ]{
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    }
\qquad
\subfloat[
    $x = 5$ ; $y = 0.40$.
    \newline
    $u \approx 14.6$ ; $v \approx 0.13$.
    \newline
    $p \approx 2.18$ ; $q \approx 0.98$.
    ]{
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    }
\newline
\subfloat[
    $x = 60$ ; $y = 0.036642$.
    \newline
    $u \approx 3.78$ ; $v \approx 0.50$.
    \newline
    $p \approx 2.20$ ; $q \approx 0.99$.]{
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    }
\qquad
\subfloat[
    $x = 60$ ; $y = 0.04$.
    \newline
    $u \approx 4.99$ ; $v \approx 0.43$.
    \newline
    $p \approx 2.40$ ; $q \approx 0.99$.
    ]{
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    }
\caption[Blabla]{Some description.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Preview, with various issues shown in red :

[image]

So I need to fix the three following issues, without minipages or the likes:

1. The figures should be well aligned on top of each others.
2. For each figure, the subcaption shouldn't having any label and be fully centered below its figure.
3. The subcaption should be made of three well separated lines (currentyly, it's too tight), and be aligned on the ; symbol.

How can I do this using only the subfig package?

I tried using the `\mathllap` and `\mathrla`p commands, but didn't got any nice looking result yet.

---

**EDIT :**  I've solved the figure alignment (issue #1) by replacing the `\newline` command (near the middle of the code) by `\\ \bigskip`.

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat less enthusiastic about `\newline`s, and get (with the help of some `tabular`s which one could also design as `array`s)

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup{figurename=Figure,margin=1cm,format=hang,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={it}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0cm,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={up}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]  % [ h ], [ b ], [ t ], [ p ]
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty,justification=centering}
\subfloat[\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}>{~;~}l@{}}
    $x = 5$ & $y = 0,33$.
    \\
    $u = 1$ & $v \approx 0.87$.
    \\
    $p \approx 1.75$ & $q \approx 0.95$.
    \end{tabular}%
    ]{%
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}%
    }
\qquad
\subfloat[\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}>{~;~}l@{}}
    $x = 5$ & $y = 0.40$.
    \\
    $u \approx 14.6$ & $v \approx 0.13$.
    \\
    $p \approx 2.18$ & $q \approx 0.98$.
    \end{tabular}%
    ]{%
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}%
    }
\\
\subfloat[\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}>{~;~}l@{}}
    $x = 60$ & $y = 0.036642$.
    \\
    $u \approx 3.78$ & $v \approx 0.50$.
    \\
    $p \approx 2.20$ & $q \approx 0.99$.
    \end{tabular}%
    ]{%
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}%
    }
\qquad
\subfloat[\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}>{~;~}l@{}}
    $x = 60$ & $y = 0.04$.
    \\
    $u \approx 4.99$ & $v \approx 0.43$.
    \\
    $p \approx 2.40$ & $q \approx 0.99$.
    \end{tabular}%
    ]{%
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}%
    }
\caption[Blabla]{Some description.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]